# Pandas: transform dataframe with processes and steps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `processes` with their ids and steps:

```
| process_id |  step_id  | 
--------------------------
|   1        |   s1      |
|   1        |   s2      |
|   2        |   s1      |
|   2        |   s3      |
|   2        |   s4      |
|   3        |   s8      |
|   3        |   s9      |
|   3        |   s2      |
|   3        |   s5      |
```

I want to create a `transitions` `DataFrame`, which would present particular movements from one step to another:

```
| process_id |  step_from  |  step_to  | 
----------------------------------------
|   1        |   s1        |   s2      |
|   2        |   s1        |   s3      |
|   2        |   s3        |   s4      |
|   3        |   s8        |   s9      |
|   3        |   s9        |   s2      |
|   3        |   s2        |   s5      |
```

I was trying to use `shift()` with `groupby()` (so I can merge one row with next one somehow for a given `process_id`), but it turned out to be too hard for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and `rename`:

```
df['step_to'] = df.groupby('process_id')['step_id'].shift(-1)

df = df.dropna(subset=['step_to']).rename(columns={'step_id':'step_from'})
print (df)
   process_id step_from step_to
0           1        s1      s2
2           2        s1      s3
3           2        s3      s4
5           3        s8      s9
6           3        s9      s2
7           3        s2      s5
```